# Does Apple's executable size limit mean for compressed or uncompressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I read from Apple's document:

- each executable file (app_name.app/app_name) must not exceed 60 MB

Which was mentioned in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf) at Page 67.
Does the size limit mean compressed or uncompressed?

Comment: As I understand from the doc this is maximum uncompressed size.

Comment: @VijayMasiwal  I guess so too, but unfortunately my uncompressed executable is larger. Really wish I was wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the maximum uncompressed app binary size, excluding assets. Assets have a different limit as part of the entire app size.

Comment: I don't consider it for uncompressed  app (ipa) binary size, but executable (app_name.app/app_name) size.

Comment: The executable is the binary.